# Error 403--Forbidden error on weblogic

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am accessing my context url as follows
http://sachina.technologic.com:7001/eqube610w2/AdminConsole
This works fine.
But if I try by adding / at the end for example
http://sachina.technologic.com:7001/eqube610w2/AdminConsole/
This gives me error as follows

This is the error

```
Error 403--Forbidden 
From RFC 2068 Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1:
10.4.4 403 Forbidden
```

The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it. Authorization will not help and the request SHOULD NOT be repeated. If the request method was not HEAD and the server wishes to make public why the request has not been fulfilled, it SHOULD describe the reason for the refusal in the entity. This status code is commonly used when the server does not wish to reveal exactly why the request has been refused, or when no other response is applicable.

Same context works fine with Tomcat don't know what is the problem with WebLogic.
Any help will be greatly appreceiated.
Thanks in adavance.

Comment: Web page not available when I try to visit it.

Answer (score -1):

it depends up on the path u set to that particular page in ur application...